# Calculate sum of certain rows (based on a uniqId) in a column without using for-loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sum

I have a matrix:

```
raw = [ 2001 1000 ; 2001 2000 ; 2001 1000 ; 2001 1000 ; 2001 2000 ; 5555 nan ; 5555 10000 ; 5555 20000 ; 5555 5000 ; 5555 20000 ; 5555 30000 ; 7777 1000 ; 7777 2000 ; 7777 3000 ; 7777 nan] ;
```

I need to find the sum of the every last 4 rows in Col2 (for each uniqId) based on the uniqIds which are in Col1.  The Col2 might also have NaNs in them.  The answer I want is:

```
[2001 nan; 2001 nan; 2001 nan; 2001 5000; 2001 6000; 5555 nan; 5555 nan; 5555 nan; 5555 nan; 5555 55000; 5555 75000; 7777 nan 7777 nan 7777 nan ; 7777 nan] ;
```

The raw matrix only has elements which have >= 4 rows of data. I CANNOT use a for-loop. Please help me with a vectorized form if possible.  I can use a while loop if required.

Comment: If it's not homework: why can't you use for-loops, but while-loops?

Comment: @John - no John.  I need it at work.  I can have the data manipulated by SQL and then transfer it to matlab along with everything else.  But it takes a lot of time for 50k rows*13 cols to be transferred!  I have the data with me.  I need a vectorized form which I cannot find myself. Thnx.

Comment: @Andrew - I know that using a 'for' loop would be rather advisable here.  However, my reluctance is because of the huge data size.  I can initialize the vector to save time.  I would still prefer to use a vectorized form.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using the functions [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) and [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html). The following assumes that each group will have at least 4 elements. Any `NaN` values present in the raw data will result in a value of `NaN` for a summation window that includes that value:

```
[~,~,index] = unique(raw(:,1));  %# Get the indices for the unique values
sumFcn = @(x) {sum(hankel([nan(3,1); x(1:numel(x)-3)],...  %# Anonymous function
                          x(numel(x)-3:end)),2)};          %#   to get the sum
                                                           %#   over each window
                                                           %#   of four values
sumPerID = accumarray(index,raw(:,2),[],sumFcn);  %# Compute the windowed sum
                                                  %#   for each unique ID
raw(:,2) = vertcat(sumPerID{:})  %# Place the results back into the second
                                 %#   column of raw
raw =

        2001         NaN
        2001         NaN
        2001         NaN
        2001        5000
        2001        6000
        5555         NaN
        5555         NaN
        5555         NaN
        5555         NaN
        5555       55000
        5555       75000
        7777         NaN
        7777         NaN
        7777         NaN
        7777         NaN
```

Comment: There is still one major issue with this gnovice - if there is any NaN data, the calculation fails: i.e. if raw = [ 2001 1000 ; 2001 2000 ; 2001 1000 ; 2001 1000 ; 2001 2000 ; 5555 nan ; 5555 10000 ; 5555 20000 ; 5555 5000 ; 5555 20000 ; 5555 30000 ] ;  The result fails for 5555.  Could you fix it please?  Thanks so much, as always!

Comment: @Maddy: You didn't mention there could be NaNs in the raw data. You should edit the question to mention that.

Comment: @gnovice - Sorry.  I have edited the main Q accordingly.  I initially assumed that any nan in the data would simple make the final answer as NaN, and so did not include it in the Q.  The Q as of now is accurate.  Thanks

Comment: @Maddy: I've updated my answer to match the new description and data in the question.

Comment: @gnovice: A pity I cannot upvote your solution again for using `hankel`.

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks, I'm actually quite proud of that trick. HANKEL may not be the most efficient solution (particularly for IDs with very large numbers of elements), but it is a lot more compact and prettier than what I had before.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `accumarray`, that might help.

Comment: Loren wrote an article on the [under-appreciated accumarray](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/20/under-appreciated-accumarray/).